# How to make a set of numbers all become the same number through a set of plus one operations?

Tags: algorithm

I am currently playing a game where there is a puzzle task:

Given `n` linear monuments, these monuments are not adjacent to the head and tail, each monument has a number `x`(1 <= `x` <= `y`) on it, attacking one of the monuments will increase the number `x` on the current monument and adjacent monuments by 1.

If the monument is already equal to `y`, the number on the monument will be changed to 1 after the attack.

For example, given a set of monuments(y is 3, z is 3):

```
1,3,2,1
```

If attacks 1, the result would be: `2,1,2,1`.

If attacks 3, the result would be: `2,1,3,1`.

Given a set of monument numbers, can all the monument numbers be changed to z (1 <= `z` <= `y`) through a set of attacks? If so, please give the shortest attack order in steps.

I have been thinking for a long time, but I have not thought of what the key point is to solve this problem. I would be much appreciate if someone are willing to tell me a solution or any idea(If you write some code, any language or pseudo code is okay). Meanwhile I will keep thinking until I worked it out.

Comment: What exactly is the input? Is z given as input?

Comment: z is 3, the line:`len(set(m)) == 1` could be changed to `all(x == z for x in m)`

Answer (score 1):

Reformulating the question: consider the heights to range from 0 to y-1 (rather than 1 to y), and for example when y is 3 and you have 4 monuments, attacking monument 2 means adding (1, 1, 1, 0) to the vector of heights with modulo 3 arithmetic. If you start with your example: 1, 3, 2, 1, (and y=z=3) you need to find a combination of monuments so that you add (2, 0, 1, 2) to the heights (modulo 3).

With that reformulation, you're being asked to find the smallest positive integer vector a1...a3 such that this matrix multiplication equation (in modulo 3 arithmetic) holds:

```
[1100] * [a0] = [2]
[1110]   [a1]   [0]
[0111]   [a2]   [1]
[0011]   [a3]   [2]
```

In this example you can solve it easily by hand:

- a0+a1 = 2 and a0+a1+a2=0, so a2=-2=1 (mod 3)
- a2+a3 = 2 so a3=1
- a1+a2+a3 = 1, so a1=2
- a0+a1 = 2 so a0=0

So you attack the second monument twice, the third and fourth once each. (This is the same as the other answer computed by exhaustion).

You might try to solve this matrix problem using linear algebra, but it's not straightforward and there's messy details when the matrix isn't invertible.

However, if you try a particular a0, then all the other variables are automatically determined simply by following the set of equations.

For example, if you try a0=1, then you have a0+a1=2 so a1=1. Then a0+a1+a2=0 so 1+1+a2=0 so a2=1. Then a1+a2+a3=1 so a3=2. Then a2+a3=2 which is impossible so the initial guess must be wrong.

It may be that there's zero, one or multiple solutions, and you might need to pick the one with the smallest sum.

In this method, a guess for a0 takes n steps to test, and there's y possible values for a0 so the total complexity is O(ny).

Answer (score 0):

There are finitely many states (namely y^n), so you can run a BFS on them.

A Python implementation:

```py
monuments = 1,3,2,1
y = 3

seen = {monuments}
queue = [[monuments]]
for *path, m in queue:
  if len(set(m)) == 1:
    print(*path, m, sep='\n')
    break
  for i in range(len(m)):
    m2 = tuple(
      (x + (abs(i-j) <= 1) - 1) % y + 1
      for j, x in enumerate(m)
    )
    if m2 not in seen:
      seen.add(m2)
      queue.append([*path, m, m2])
```

Or if `z` is given, replace `len(set(m)) == 1` with `set(m) == {z}`.

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RZDBboMwDIa1a57Cl6nJGipBL1M1noRxSIVZ6RqTQpCKpj3JLr1sD7WnmQ20u0SO_fuz_X_9hDEeWrpev4dYJ8-_D6VvafBIsYccUru1mU3VyPFWqR6ROPq4Sz7VecABOVcU92RZqrrt4Cm4eLDgoSGYVDsF0NRwQtI9Ru2NgZxHSBogdA1Ffeux0GPIV6-0MlN136F750i4jQA7R2-oBcWYmeAzXiMO4YR6-gPoC6xBu32vm-Ro4IWHGUjkeYSRS-miE-rRwkXAKEd0LiKDp_L88t7MpzaKRmzYLb0Sb1xVaZ-ZJTUdu3EhIFW6-D_JZ6WZXV7Mvpn-Bw)):

```
(1, 3, 2, 1)
(2, 1, 3, 1)
(3, 2, 1, 1)
(3, 3, 2, 2)
(3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Get it!  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @Criwran Added an implementation and result for the example input.